# The Price must be greater than 0. Please, check the Price, Quantity and Format Policy and Product Settings

Tags: product, amazon, m2epro, magento-2.0.1

[image]

While working M2EPRO extension in magento 2 for listing of product getting :
"The Price must be greater than 0. Please, check the Price, Quantity and Format Policy and Product Settings."
Unable to find any solution regarding this error please help !!

Comment: Please ask to M2Pro support , they will help you